# How to change mac OS behavior when closing windows (Mission Control)

Tags: mac, mission-control

I have realized the following annoying behavior from Mac OS. Suppose the following situation:

1. Open app A on Desktop 1 (*window A1*)
2. Move to Desktop 2
3. Open app B on Desktop 2
4. Open another window of app A on Desktop 2 (*window A2*)
5. Close *window A2*

What mac OS does after closing *window A2* to is to switch automatically to Desktop 1. This is particularly annoying since you are working on Desktop 2 and would like to remain there.

How to change this behavior?

I am currently using mac OS 14.2, but the solution might be a general setup of Mission Control. However, the options of Mission control found in settings do no explicitly addess this issue.

Comment: You're closing one of two windows of an app. The app is currently frontmost… so it switches to the remaining open window for that app. Expected behaviour. Windows in a Mac app are not separate instances of the app, they're multi-document windows to the same app instance.

Comment: However, such behavior is not expected on "Windows OS". For an analogy, try the following on "Windows OS" and on "Mac OS". Work on Desktop 1: open App A (A1), open App B (B1), open another window of App A (A2), close A2. The result on Windows OS is to show B1 because it is the next window in the stack. The result on Mac OS is to show A1. I think that showing the next window in the stack is more "natural", because it relates to a physical stack. This behavior is what I want to turn off, which permeates to a multiple desktop workspace.

Comment: You're comparing Apples & oranges. The two OSes do not behave in the same way. They are built on different paradigms. You're also trying to use one app across two Spaces - something it was never designed to do.